# I am creating a database and i keep getting "INVALID IDENTIFIER" Error

Tags: sql, database, oracle, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

```
CREATE TABLE Review(
VersionID VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
rating INT,
FOREIGN KEY (PaperID) REFERENCES Paper(PaperID),
FOREIGN KEY (Revi) REFERENCES Paper(PaperID)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it this way:

```
CREATE TABLE Review(
VersionID VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
rating INT,
constraint constraint_1_name FOREIGN KEY (PaperID) REFERENCES Paper(PaperID),
constraint constraint_2_name FOREIGN KEY (Revi) REFERENCES Paper(PaperID)
);
```

(Of course instead of paperId/Revi you should use existing field names...)